# How does command-not-found determines if user is administrator

Tags: server, apt, sudo

I am administrator of two ubuntu servers. On one of them, when I try to run a command (for instance `irb1.9.1`) from a package that is not installed, I get the following message:

```
The program 'irb1.9.1' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
```

On the other server, I get the following answer:

```
The program 'irb1.9.1' is currently not installed.  To run 'irb1.9.1' please ask your administrator to install the package 'ruby1.9.1'
```

I can `sudo` on both servers, so I don't understand how the first one knows I can install the package myself and shows me the command to run, while the second doesn't.

Where does the difference come from and how can I get the second server to give me the command like the first server?

**Edit** to answer Braiam's comment, `apt-cache policy` return the same on both servers:

```
$ apt-cache policy command-not-found
command-not-found:
  Installed: 0.3ubuntu7.1
  Candidate: 0.3ubuntu7.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.3ubuntu7.1 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.3ubuntu7 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy command-not-found`?

Comment: @Braiam I edited my question with this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating the topic a bit more, I found that `command-not-found` was using the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py` script, which contains the following line:

```
self.user_can_sudo = grp.getgrnam("sudo")[2] in posix.getgroups() or grp.getgrnam("admin")[2] in posix.getgroups()
```

So basically anyone in the `sudo` or `admin` groups will be considered as an administrator. One of the machines was configured to use the `wheel` group instead, so `visudo` would show:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

On the server I wasn't member of the `sudo` or `admin` groups, so `command-not-found` wouldn't know I could execute `apt-get` commands with `sudo`. After adding myself to the `sudo` group as well, I now get the apt-get command to execute printed out on the terminal.

Comment: Note that on Debian 8 "Jessie", the script is looking for the group `admin` (which didn't exist upon OS installation).

Answer (score 0):

Difference probably occurs because you use different bash versions or different shells. Use:

```
echo $SHELL
bash --version
```

to check your current shell and/or your current bash version.

Comment: Both answer `/bin/bash` and `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release`. One with `(i686-pc-linux-gnu)` and one with `
(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. If that's the reason for the difference it looks like a bug...

Comment: @Calimo So, there are different versions of bash. One is for 32bit and another one for 64bit.